# Data points' value are visible on the chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

When I embed this chart (https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/time/line-point-data.html) to my dashboard, I get data values visible on my plot. How can I remove them?
[image]

Comment: Can you please share you code for the chart or create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: Presumably you've included the datalabels plugin in your page without configuring it appropriately. But since you've not provided code I've voted to close as off-topic.